how can I get chat folders using pyrogram in Python?
I'm looking for a way to get all the folders that are in a user account, I can't find how to do this in the docs
I've seen this in the documentation:

class pyrogram.raw.types.Folder Folder.
Constructor of Folder.
Details: Layer: 158
ID: FF544E65
Parameters: id (int 32-bit) – Folder ID.
title (str) – Folder title.
autofill_new_broadcasts (bool, optional) – Automatically add new
channels to this folder.
autofill_public_groups (bool, optional) – Automatically add joined new
public supergroups to this folder.
autofill_new_correspondents (bool, optional) – Automatically add new
private chats to this folder.
photo (ChatPhoto, optional) – Folder picture.


did you find some answer?
